# React Material UI Insert and delete row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react and using free version of 'Devias kit' theme from material ui.
Now I'm stuck with some issues inserting and deleting rows into the table.
I have checked that data has been changed when either insert or delete button has been pressed but not showing changes on display.
these below are my code. 
please let me know, what has been gone wrong.

```
//UserTable.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import moment from 'moment';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import uuid from 'uuid/v1';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import RemoveCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircle';
import {
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Checkbox,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TablePagination,
  IconButton,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
  Button
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

  root: {
    height: '100%'
  },
  content: {
    padding: 0,
    height: '90%'
  },
  inner: {
    minWidth: 1050
  },
  nameContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  actions: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    height: '10%',
  },
  editRow: {
    // float: 'left'
  },
}));

const UsersTable = props => {

  const { className, users, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([]);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(100);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [userSet,setUsers] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectAll = event => {
    const { users } = props;

    let selectedUsers;

    if (event.target.checked) {
      selectedUsers = users.map(user => user.id);
    } else {
      selectedUsers = [];
    }

    setSelectedUsers(selectedUsers);
  };

  const handleSelectOne = (event, id) => {
    const selectedIndex = selectedUsers.indexOf(id);
    let newSelectedUsers = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selectedUsers.length - 1) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(
        selectedUsers.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selectedUsers.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelectedUsers(newSelectedUsers);
  };

  const handlePageChange = (event, page) => {
    setPage(page);
  };

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = event => {
    setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleRowAdd = () => {
    let newUserSet = [];

    const newRow = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: 'Ekaterina Tankova',
      address: {
        country: 'USA',
        state: 'West Virginia',
        city: 'Parkersburg',
        street: '2849 Fulton Street'
      },
      amount: '300',
      product: '885178382529',
      email: 'ekaterina.tankova@devias.io',
      phone: '304-428-3097',
      avatarUrl: '/images/avatars/avatar_3.png',
      createdAt: 1555016400000
    };

    newUserSet = newUserSet.concat(userSet,newRow);
    setUsers(newUserSet);
  }

  const handleRowDelete = () => {
    let newUserSet = users;

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedUsers.length; i++) {
      newUserSet = newUserSet.filter(user => user.id !== selectedUsers[i])
    }
    setUsers(newUserSet);
    handlePopClose();
  }

  const handlePopClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handlePopClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      {...rest}
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
    >
      <CardContent className={classes.content}>
        <PerfectScrollbar>
          <div className={classes.inner}>
            <Table>
              <TableHead aria-label="sticky table">
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={selectedUsers.length === users.length}
                      color="default"
                      indeterminate={
                        selectedUsers.length > 0 &&
                        selectedUsers.length < users.length
                      }
                      onChange={handleSelectAll}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column1</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column2</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column3</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column4</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column5</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column6</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column7</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column8</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>column9</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {users.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map(user => (
                  <TableRow
                    className={classes.tableRow}
                    hover
                    key={user.id}
                    selected={selectedUsers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1}
                  >
                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                      <Checkbox
                        checked={selectedUsers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1}
                        color="default"
                        onChange={event => handleSelectOne(event, user.id)}
                        value="true"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.product}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.phone}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{moment(user.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.amount}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{moment(user.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.amount}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </div>
        </PerfectScrollbar>
      </CardContent>


      <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
        <IconButton 
          className={classes.editRow}
          onClick={handleRowAdd}
        >
          <AddCircleIcon className={classes.editBtn}/>
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton 
          className={classes.editRow}
          onClick={handlePopClickOpen}
        >
          <RemoveCircleIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={users.length}
          onChangePage={handlePageChange}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleRowsPerPageChange}
          page={page}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[100, 500, 1000, 999999]}
        />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

UsersTable.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default UsersTable;
```

a

```
// NonRegularList.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

import { UsersToolbar, UsersTable } from './components';
import mockData from './data';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    height: '94%',
  },
  content: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    height: '100%',
  }
}));

const NonRegularList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [users] = useState(mockData);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <UsersToolbar />
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <UsersTable 
          users={users} 
          editable={}
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NonRegularList;
```

this is my structure of views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2fWX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning an array to another variable assigns the reference to it.
So by mutating `newUserSet` you are actually mutating the state itself.
So it doesn't re-render on state change using setState.

You want to create a new array from your state using [...array] then mutate it

Try the code below.

For deleting:

```
const handleRowDelete = () => {
        let newUserSet1 = [...users];

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedUsers.length; i++) {
      newUserSet1 = newUserSet1.filter(user => user.id !== selectedUsers[i])
    }
    setUsers(newUserSet1);
    handlePopClose();
  }
```

For inserting

```
const handleRowAdd = () => {
    let newUserSet1 = [];

const newRow = {
  id: uuid(),
  name: 'Ekaterina Tankova',
  address: {
    country: 'USA',
    state: 'West Virginia',
    city: 'Parkersburg',
    street: '2849 Fulton Street'
  },
  amount: '300',
  product: '885178382529',
  email: 'ekaterina.tankova@devias.io',
  phone: '304-428-3097',
  avatarUrl: '/images/avatars/avatar_3.png',
  createdAt: 1555016400000
};

newUserSet1 = [...newUserSet]
newUserSet1 = newUserSet1.concat(userSet,newRow);
setUsers(newUserSet1);
}
```

In render, you should render your state instead of props after you set your state using props in useEffect

```
{newUserSet.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map(user => (
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just tried your code and it does not work either...

Comment: The problem is you render users which comes from props. But while inserting or deleting you make changes ti newUserSet but you are not using it in render.

Comment: Glad, I was able to help. Would you accept my answer then?